# Create a legend with pandas and matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

This is my first attempt at plotting with python and I'm having problems creating a legend.

These are my imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
```

I load my data like this:

```
data = pandas.read_csv( 'data/output/limits.dat', sep=r"\s+", encoding = 'utf-8' )
```

and plot it like this:

```
axdata = data.plot( label = '$|U|^{2}$' , x = 'mass', y = 'U2',
                    style = '-s', markeredgecolor = 'none' )
```

Apparently axdata is now an  `AxesSubplot`.

Now I want to create a legend as described [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) like this:

```
plt.legend( (line1), ('label1') )
```

but I don't know how to extract a `line` object from an `AxesSubplot`

`plt.legend()` on its own works, but I only want some of my lines to feature in the legend. Is this the right approach? Is there another command I can use here?

**EDIT**:

For example, if I try:

```
plt.legend( [axdata], ['U2'])
```

I get the error:

```
~/.virtualenvs/science/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py:613:
UserWarning: Legend does not support Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
Use proxy artist instead.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

(str(orig_handle),))
```

I haven't worked out what a proxy artist is yet but I think it is a tool for when you are using a non-default graphical object, which I thought probably was not the case here because I am trying to produce a normal matlibplot plot. The words 'non-default' and 'normal' are mine - I'm not sure what they mean yet.

**ANOTHER EDIT:** (because I misread the comment )

`plt.legend()` on it's own doesn't output anything to the console but the resulting plot now has a legend auto-generated from the plotted data.

Comment: Anyway you can give a little more information? Maybe an example of what plt.legend() outputs and what you want the legend to output? This would greatly help us understand how to help you :)

Comment: What happens if you do `ax.legend()` and `plt.draw()`?

Comment: I get a legend but it contains entries for all the lines not just the one which returned my original axdata object.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think what you want to do is be able to display a legend for a subset of the lines on your plot. This should do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400, 4), columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
ax1 = df.cumsum().plot()
lines, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(lines[:2], labels[:2], loc='best')  # legend for first two lines only
```

Giving

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, when I call `data.plot()` ( which according to the pandas docs is supposed to be a wrapper for `plt.plot()` ), the returned object does not support `get_legend_handles_labels()`. I can't work out how to extract lines from it or turn it into whatever type `ax1` is your example

Comment: `ax1` is a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` returned from the call to `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`. It is exactly what `data.plot()` should return. Without running code to debug I'm not sure what the problem might be, sorry.

Comment: It was a typo :(. Turns out I spelt labels wrong. Thanks for your demo.